# Retrieve Sharing rules via tooling api

Tags: tooling-api, workbench, sharing-rule

so firstly I am not very clear about what the tooling api on workbench is/does (I guess basically retrieve information about metadata objects?), but I have been able utilize to help me greatly with some tasks. For example, I was very happy to use it to retrieve all the data on all validation rules in our entire instance, which was very helpful for many tasks.

Now I am trying to figure out if I can use it to retrieve all the information on all sharing rules for all objects in our instance, but I am trying everything I can figure out from researching on the internet, and I still have not been successful.

Is it possible? If yes, I think my question is basically what object to call from?